# Adding eventListener to checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom-events

Can I add an `eventListener` in `JavaScript` to a checkbox or do I have to use the attribute in html `onclick = someFunc()` to trigger a function.
I set a up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JsUWv/5366/) where I tried to add an `eventListener`, but that does not give me the expected output.

```
var checkb = document.getElementById("checkbox1");

(function() {

    checkbFunc(checkb);

    function checkbFunc(checkb) {
        checkb.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            if (checkb.checked) {
                alert("i am checked");

            } else {
                alert("i am not checked")
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You never execute the function. Do you mean to *Immediately Invoke* that Function Expression?

Comment: See this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JsUWv/5368/)!

Comment: @AndrewL. with other functions, written like this, it works!

Comment: `(function() { ... });` never executes the anonymous function. But if you change it to `(function() { ... })();` then it does and your fiddle works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just unwrap your code from all the functions, and use the `change` event instead, and it should work fine

```
var checkb = document.getElementById("checkbox1");

checkb.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    if (this.checked) {
        alert("i am checked");
    } else {
        alert("i am not checked")
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JsUWv/5369/)

Comment: Or execute the function expression using `(function() { ... })();`

Answer (score 0):

You can do other way around like this

```
var checkb = document.getElementById("checkbox1");

(function() {

    checkbFunc(checkb);

    function checkbFunc(checkb) {
        checkb.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            if( checkb.checked ) {
                alert("i am checked");

            } else {
                alert("i am not checked")
            }
        });
    }
})(); // <--added this
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JsUWv/5370/)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply remove your anonymous function

```js
var checkb = document.getElementById("checkbox1");

checkbFunc(checkb);
    
function checkbFunc(checkb) {
  checkb.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if( checkb.checked ) {
      alert("i am checked");

    } else {
      alert("i am not checked")
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/>
```

Or, better, use JQuery document.ready block.

Answer (score 0):

your code is not working because the main anonymous functions is not executed.

The code below should work for you.

```
var checkb = document.getElementById("checkbox1");

(function() {

  checkbFunc(checkb);

    function checkbFunc(checkb) {
        console.log(checkb);
        checkb.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            if( checkb.checked ) {
                alert("i am checked");

            } else {
                alert("i am not checked")
            }
        });
    }
}() // Add these round braces );
```